# extract dataframe from pandas datafeed in backtrader

Tags: python, pandas

I have my pandas backtrader datafeed created and passed in via:

```
data = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname= **my_data.candles_to_backtrader(pandas))
cerebro.adddata(data)
```

I'm creating a new `indicator` that needs to get back out the `dataframe` from the `data feed`

or actually just perform operations like `min`, `max` on the data.

in my indicator I have:

```
def next(self):
    ...
    minr = datas[0].min()
    ...
```

this is not working, mentioning:

```
AttributeError: 'Lines_LineSeries_DataSeries_OHLC_OHLCDateTime_Abst' object has no attribute 'min'
```

any clues?

Answer (score 3):

I got from several sources that backtrader is not (and not going to) support calculations with pandas dataframe.

Here's the method to convert `self.datas[0]` to a pandas dataframe, passing `len(self)` in too, to support proper backtesting.

here's the code:

```
def __bt_to_pandas__(self, btdata, len):
    get = lambda mydata: mydata.get(ago=0, size=len)

    fields = {
        'open': get(btdata.open),
        'high': get(btdata.high),
        'low': get(btdata.low),
        'close': get(btdata.close),
        'volume': get(btdata.volume)
    }
    time = [btdata.num2date(x) for x in get(btdata.datetime)]

    return pd.DataFrame(data=fields, index=time)
```

Where `btdata` can be simply `self.datas[0]` and `len` can be `len(self)`

hope this helps

Comment: *backtrader* doesn't have to support calculations with `pandas`. That's something for the end user. The answer you got (single source): https://community.backtrader.com/topic/1448/convert-datas-0-into-a-pandas-dataframe, tells you that *backtrader* won't import packages which are not in the standard library. You are free to import them. Furthermore, in the same topic you ask for `Dataframe` you could share your code.

Comment: thanks, you mean I should be posting this code there too?

Answer (score 1):

*backtrader* is not `pandas` and it is not conceived to be used as a `Dataframe`.

From your example:

```
def next(self):
    ...
    minr = datas[0].min()
    ...
```

It should actually be `self.datas[0]` or even better `self.data0` or `self.data`, which simplifies things, but that's not the point.

The key point is here

```
    minr = datas[0].min()
```

First:

- When you are referring to `self.datas[0]` and doing something with it, you are referring to the `close` price. Why? Because the industry settled on that a long time ago and it also enables the development of generic indicators that do not have to reference a specific field (when you have *Indicators* on *Indicators* on *Indicators* it becomes obvious that being generic is the way to go)

Second:

- You are apparently asking for the minimum of the entire, already gone through, series.

  Indicators as conceived have a lookback period and don't (usually, but you may) look at the entire series back.

Third:

- Even if you have used a `Dataframe` as your input, *backtrader* doesn't work with this structure internally (it is conscious design decision) and each of the elements which make a price bar or the output of an indicator are individual arrays.

No. *backtrader* is not a `Dataframe` and it is not meant to be used as one. You can always slice the desired *lines* and create a `Dataframe` or `Series` from them.

See: [Backtrader Documentation - Platform Concepts](https://www.backtrader.com/docu/concepts.html) and the Section: *Slicing*

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, I appreciate your view and I have my reasons for your 1st, 2nd and 3rd points. I'm about to post the method I ended up writing to obtain dataframe out of backtrader datafeeds.

Answer (score -1):

> AttributeError: 'Lines_LineSeries_DataSeries_OHLC_OHLCDateTime_Abst'
>   object has no attribute 'min'

this means you are trying to get the min of a Abst object or objects

the reason of this issue maybe

> You probably have a 2.0 account and the code is failing to receive the contractdetails from the server. You need a legacy account.

qutoe from :[backtrader link](https://community.backtrader.com/topic/571/attributeerror-lines_lineseries_dataseries_ohlc_ohlcdatetime_abst-object-has-no-attribute-contractdetails/2)

so solution is find the correct series to get min

> minr = datas["something different"].min()

if you can provide the data sample, i can help detail

or if you really wanna sort datetime , u can always try convert it to unix timestamp first

Comment: that's why I was looking into getting back a pandas dataframe in my indicator, in a dataframe df.min() means something different from datafeed.min(). I'd like to exploit the power of pandas in my indicator, rather than reinventing the wheel dealing with a data feed.

Comment: this page automatic min is this what you r looking for? https://www.backtrader.com/docu/inddev.html?highlight=indicator

Comment: I'm looking to use pandas to manipulate my backtracker data feed, the code I posted was just an example showing the problem.

Comment: `this means you are trying to get the min of a DateTime object or objects` this a compleletly wrong assumption. It is wrong.

Comment: dude,whats the difference between your and mine? the point is just telling him,that object is not min operation applicable